# Badge pages can say "recently awarded" but display all recipients

Tags: discussion, badges

The badge page text can be confusing. For example, the [`[python]` gold badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/51/) says:

> 17 Users earned this badge. Recently awarded to:

and then lists 17 users. This is confusing, because the phrase "recently awarded to" makes me think it's not the whole list, just some users that recently received the badge, though the page lists all users.

Is this just nitpicking or has anyone else found this unclear?

Comment: congrats on getting the badge. I'm still about ~300 away.

Comment: *gooooooooooooooooooooooooooooold!!!*

Comment: The way I see it, when there are more than 60 awardees, it paginates - so you would be looking at the "recently awarded to" list on page 1

Comment: @Jose K: still I think that would be unclear.

Comment: @Jeff: are you alright :) ?

Comment: @Jose I think your point does not hold because "recently awarded" shows up on all pages, even on the last page. So it is surely a wrong phrasing. I think it should be changed to "newest first" or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You're not the only one who has noticed this, though I don't think I was ever confused by it - it's a case of "I know what they wanted to say."

There's a very simple fix for it: remove the word *recently*. I think "Awarded to" is perfectly sufficient as a page title. To make the chronology apparent, the date the badge was awarded could be displayed next to each name - kind of like the badge pages on MSO already do it. (The other sites badge pages don't have the date currently, though this is perhaps changing?)

Answer (score 2):

The list is presented in reverse order of awarding, so those at the top of the page are the most recent recipients.

I'm not sure how you could present this data any different.

"Most recent" is a vague term does it mean the most N recent recipients or those who received the badge in the last M days/weeks. In the former case the list could include a relatively old recipient if it's a rarely awarded badge. The number of people on the list will depend on the values of N and M and your bound to upset someone.

Then there'd have to be an extra click to see the full list (yes I know there is if the list is paginated, but that's not the point).